# Is it possible to perform other processing after bigquery sink in python?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing a pipeline with following process:

```py
1. Read pubsub messages with attribute 'uid' which is the unique id for this message
2. Store the message in Bigquery, the data format is 
    uid | message data | status
    ------------------------------
      1 | {XXXXX}      | new

3. process the message data 
4. update the message to set the status to 'complete'
    uid | message data | status
    ------------------------------
      1 | {XXXXX}      | complete
```

**I got three questions:**

**Q1.How to continue with further processing after bigquery sink**

If I use bigqueryIO to implement step2 like

```py
p=beam.Pipeline(runner=known_args.runner,options=pipeline_options)
message=(
        p
        |beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.inputSub,with_attributes=True))
        |'format complete data output'>> beam.ParDo(format_result_for_bq())
        |'write complete data to bq' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table='XXXXX',
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR
        )
        |'further process' >> beam.ParDo(further_processing_fn())
    )
```

step 'further process' can only get the output of beam.io.WriteToBigQuery instead of the original message.

I also consider to use side output, but this is hard to ensure the 'further process' will not start until the data has been successfully written to bigquery.

Can you please help to advice how to achieve the goal?

**Q2. Is it appropriate to perform bigquery operation inside ParDo**

Given the process logic above, this is my code

```py
class saveData(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        client=bigquery.Client()
        query="insert into `XXXXX` values ('{}','{}','{}')"\
                    .format(element[1].get('uid'),element[0],'ongoing')
        query_job = client.query(query)
        result = query_job.result()
        res=(element[0],element[1],'ongoing')
        yield res

class businessProcess(beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, element,*args, **kwargs):
       print("business process logic")
       res=(element[0],element[1],'complete')
       yield res

class updateRow(beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, element,*args, **kwargs):
       attribute = element[1]
       query = 'update `XXXXXX` set status = "complete" where uid="{}" ' \
               .format(attribute.get('uid'))
       client=bigquery.Client()
       query_job = client.query(query)
       result=query_job.result()
......
p=beam.Pipeline(runner=known_args.runner,options=pipeline_options)
message=(
        p
        |beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.inputSub,with_attributes=True))
        |'insert to bq with status ongoing'>> beam.ParDo(saveData())
        |'business process'>> beam.ParDo(businessProcess())
        |'update bq' >> beam.ParDo(udpateRow())
    )
```

I don't think this is the typical beam approach to implement the requirement, can you please help to advice what's the best practice to handle such requirement?

**Q3. How to pass multiple input into ParDo ?**

If I need to pass 4 input items into a ParDo function, how to do that in python?  side input only support 2 input in my understanding, am I right?

Comment: The last part `udpateRow` after the sink to `BigQuery` needs to be done at real time ?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be done in real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, I propose you the following pattern :

```
Topic 1 -> Job Dataflow 1 -> Multi Sink -> Write Result to BigQuery
                                        -> Write Result to Pub Sub Topic 2

Topic 2 -> Job Dataflow 2 -> Apply Business Transformations -> Write Result to BigQuery
```

- A first `Dataflow` job reads data from the topic 1
- The job 1 applies a multi sink, one to BigQuery, the other to a Pub Sub topic 2
- A second `Dataflow` job read data from topic 2
- The job 2 applies your business transformations in a `ParDo` or `Map`
- The job 2 sinks the result to `BigQuery`

With this pattern, you can apply your use case in real time.
You need to separate your logic in 2 `Dataflow` job.

I saw an `update` in your second example, usually `BigQuery` in streaming mode use `append` instead of `update` and `BigQueryIO` doesn't support update.

If you have to deal with duplicates in `BigQuery`, you have to think to the best approach for you and this need can be handled outside of the `Dataflow` streaming job (`BigQuery` view + batch job).

Comment: Thanks for the advice which opens a new door for me.